# Why can't I update or delete the new import of excel data in kendo grid?

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid, bind, import-from-excel

I import the Excel file to server and the server return the JSON data to client. but after the new JSON data binding to the kendo grid dataSource, I can't update or delete this or these datas? What can I do to resolve this problem?

This is the form submit js code:

```
var form = $('#idForm');
var grid = $('#demo2').data('kendoGrid');

form.submit(function (e) {

  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    //async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.result) {
            ***grid.dataSource.data(response.data);***
            $('#moneyin').text(response.context.moneyin);
            $('#moneyout').text(response.context.moneyout);
            $('#moneyleft').text(response.context.moneyleft);
        } else {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
  });
  //e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
  return false;
});

var url = site_url + 'inline_edit/';
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: site_url + 'initial/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        create: {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        destroy: {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            //if (operation == "read") {
            //    return {
            //        page: options.page,
            //        pageSize: options.pageSize,
            //        start: $('#start').val(),
            //        end: $('#end').val()
            //    }
            //}
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                for (var k = 0; k < options.models.length; k++) {
                    var date_str = date2str(options.models[k].date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    var recor_str = date2str(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    options.models[k].date = date_str;
                    options.models[k].recordate = recor_str;
                }
                return {
                    'operation': operation,
                    'models': kendo.stringify(options.models)
                };
            }
        }
    },
    requestEnd: function (e) {
        if (e.response && e.response.context) {
            $('#moneyin').text(e.response.context.moneyin);
            $('#moneyout').text(e.response.context.moneyout);
            $('#moneyleft').text(e.response.context.moneyleft);
        }
    },
    //serverPaging: true,
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 7,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            //data type of the field {Number|String|Boolean|Date|datetime} default is String
            fields: {
                id: {
                    type: "number",
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: false
                },
                date: {

                    type: "date",
                    defaultValue: new Date(),
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                fundbefore: {
                    type: "number",
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: true
                },
                moneyin: {
                    type: "number",
                    validation: {
                        min: 0,
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                moneyout: {
                    type: "number",
                    validation: {
                        min: 0,
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                fundafter: {
                    type: "number",
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: true
                },
                charge: {
                    type: "string",
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                reason: {
                    type: 'textarea',
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                recordate: {
                    type: 'date',
                    editable: false,
                    defaultValue: new Date()
                },
                modify: {
                    editable: false,
                    defaultValue: user_name
                }
            }
        },
        data: function (response) {
            if (response.result) {
                return response.data;
            } else {
                return alert(response.message);
            }

        },
        total: function (response) {
            return response.total;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by update and delete?

Comment: such as addRow() ,command['edit', 'destroy'] which are provided by the kendo grid. And all of them can't trigger the server request after new data binding to the kendo grid  @Japi

Comment: Show your grid transport and schema definitions

Comment: @Japi I hava shown them

Comment: Did not see anything wrong on your source. Any console errors?

Comment: Thank you very much! @Japi I have solved this prolbem. It's the incorrect code format that leads to the problem!

Comment: Glad  to hear that! @frank-zhi